# how to register css form code behind in asp.net web forms

Tags: .net, asp.net, webforms

I have <% %> blocks already on my master page head tag and i want to register a css from code behind.

I have already tried the approach mentioned [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View3214BB4D-8DAC-4149-9168-0D1F7D357432.htm)

but that won't work.

I tried something like this

```
 <link type="text/css" href="<%= this.BaseUrl %>/styles/styles.css" />
```

Which did not work too.. it works for script references but not for css.

Any idea how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys got it working...!

Never thought it would be this simple.. :D

Here is the code:

Master page Head tag has :

```
<link type="text/css" href="#" runat="server" id="cssID" />
```

master page code behind has following in page load:

```
cssID.Href = string.Format("{0}/styles/styles.css", this.StyleUrl);
```